# ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of multilabel-indicator and multiclass targets in CNN

Tags: cnn, image-classification, convolutional-neural-network

I am fairly new to ML and CNN, and this is my first attempt. I have managed to get my model to run, and now I am trying to produce a confusion matrix and classification report, but I am receiving an error. I have put the code below for you to see. A bit of context on my dataset is a dataset of 9,339 images and classifying these images based on families they could belong to and in total there are 25 families/classes. The dataset is named Malimg.

The code:

```
import numpy as np
import graphviz
import keras
from sklearn.utils import class_weight
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten, Activation, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, BatchNormalization
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from ann_visualizer.visualize import ann_viz
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
from sklearn.metrics import multilabel_confusion_matrix, classification_report, confusion_matrix


path_to_data = "malimg_dataset"


train_test_generate_batches = ImageDataGenerator()
batch = train_test_generate_batches.flow_from_directory(directory=path_to_data, target_size=(64,64), batch_size=10000)
imgs, labels = next(batch) #generates batches of data from the path of the directory 
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(imgs/255.,labels, train_size=0.7, test_size=0.3) #splits the dataset into training and testing samples with 30% of the overall samples being test data.


num_classes = 25


model = Sequential()


model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(64,64,3)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam', metrics=['accuracy'])


y_train_new = np.argmax(y_train, axis=1)
class_weights = class_weight.compute_class_weight('balanced', np.unique(y_train_new), y_train_new)


history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), epochs=10,  class_weight=class_weights)
scores = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)

model.summary()

Y_pred = np.argmax(model.predict(X_test),axis=1)
print('Confusion Matrix')
print(multilabel_confusion_matrix(y_test, Y_pred))
print('Classification Report')
```

The error I receive is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-f1724cc7d7f9> in <module>
      1 Y_pred = np.argmax(model.predict(X_test),axis=1)
      2 print('Confusion Matrix')
----> 3 print(multilabel_confusion_matrix(y_test, Y_pred))

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/projectnew/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     70                           FutureWarning)
     71         kwargs.update({k: arg for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args)})
---> 72         return f(**kwargs)
     73     return inner_f
     74 

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/projectnew/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/_classification.py in multilabel_confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred, sample_weight, labels, samplewise)
    436 
    437     """
--> 438     y_type, y_true, y_pred = _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)
    439     if sample_weight is not None:
    440         sample_weight = column_or_1d(sample_weight)

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/projectnew/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/_classification.py in _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)
     89     if len(y_type) > 1:
     90         raise ValueError("Classification metrics can't handle a mix of {0} "
---> 91                          "and {1} targets".format(type_true, type_pred))
     92 
     93     # We can't have more than one value on y_type => The set is no more needed

ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of multilabel-indicator and multiclass targets
```

Could anyone give me any context into what is going on? Perhaps suggesting what the code should look like if possible. This is my first attempt but I am sure it has something to do with the fact I have 25 different classes and it isn't liking the fact that I do. I initially was using confusion_matrix but then tried multilabel_confusion_matrix as I thought this may solve my issue but it did not.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. You have to convert tests labels in single-digits instead of one-hot encoding.

To achieve this I changed the confusion matrix code from:

```
Y_pred = np.argmax(model.predict(X_test),axis=1)
print('Confusion Matrix')
print(multilabel_confusion_matrix(y_test, Y_pred))
print('Classification Report')
```

To:

```
y_test_arg=np.argmax(y_test,axis=1)
Y_pred = np.argmax(model.predict(X_test),axis=1)
print('Confusion Matrix')
print(confusion_matrix(y_test_arg, Y_pred))
```